# how to rewrite wp-admin url to some other folder using htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to rewrite a simple RewriteRule but i guess it doesn't turn up good. I created a htaccess file in wordpress wp-admin folder and i tried to rename the wp-admin directory name in my localhost.Here is the code i tried

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ hello
```

Just for testing i had done this in my localhost. I want to start from simple pattern not complex pattern so i tried other simple pattern `wp-admin` and replacement as `hello`

```
  RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
  RewriteRule wp-admin hello
```

When i go to `http://localhost/my_site/hello` i can't able to direct to wp-admin for this am getting 404 error. When i try `http://localhost/my_site/wp-admin` am getting internal server error.

I think the rewrite rule is not good in my try. I have one more doubt should place the `.htaccess` file in the wp-admin directory or in the my site root directory in my_site or should i place in every directory which am trying to change the folder name on the fly.

What wrong am i doing here.Any help please?

Comment: I think you've got it the wrong around. I think you want the admin panel under `/hello`, right?

Comment: yes exactly @FritsvanCampen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^hello(.*)$ wp-admin$1 [QSA]
```

Will change:

```
http://yourdomain.com/yourwp/hello
http://yourdomain.com/yourwp/hello/path/in/admin
```

to

```
http://yourdomain.com/yourwp/wp-admin
http://yourdomain.com/yourwp/wp-admin/path/in/admin
```

The `QSA` flag is useful for compatibility.

Comment: I want my admin panel under hello directory fake name like `http://localhost/my_site/hello/options.php` instead of `http://localhost/my_site/wp-admin/options.php`

Comment: That's what this rewrite rule does .. is it not working for you?

Comment: Then you will need to disable the `/wp-admin/` links, so noone but you, can access it directly

Comment: yes it is not working am getting internal server error for wp-admin and 404 error for hello.Wait i'll check. Thanks +1

Comment: error log - `[Thu Dec 05 18:12:37.833559 2013] [core:alert] [pid 3832:tid 1484] [client 127.0.0.1:55542] E:/wamp1/wamp/www/wp_twentythirteen/wp-admin/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Thu Dec 05 18:19:45.327010 2013] [core:alert] [pid 3832:tid 1484] [client 127.0.0.1:55612] E:/wamp1/wamp/www/wp_twentythirteen/wp-admin/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: Did you forget to enable `mod_rewrite`? :P Look in the `httpd.conf`, you'll see a bunch `LoadModule` calls, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: it is there.Here is the code `RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^hello(.*)$ wp-admin$1 [QSA]`

Comment: oh just a min.I'll check

Comment: i uncommented the line from `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` to `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: Still same problem here is the same error log `[Thu Dec 05 18:36:30.473501 2013] [core:alert] [pid 3832:tid 1484] [client 127.0.0.1:55795] E:/wamp1/wamp/www/wp_twentythirteen/wp-admin/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: Well that's odd. Double check everything?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42587/discussion-between-sun-and-frits-van-campen)

Comment: `<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>` In httpd.conf is this fine?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this in XAMPP it is working but not in WAMP @FritsvanCampen

Answer (score 1):

Here is my wordpress .htaccess with only one custom redirect, but you can understand the idea:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I would recommend you remove the `IfModule`. The only thing this does is make sure Apache doesn't refuse to start up when mod_rewrite isn't available, but you _need_ this module or your login wont work.

Comment: That's what WordPress generates on it's own. I just added `RewriteRule ^login/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]` line.

Comment: All rules except your custom one are optional rules, they mostly just do some compatibility that isn't usually required. I'm guessing you have some hard-coded links to `/login`. Anyway, just a tip ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help +1. just give me simple rules i can't understand all.I need understand so that i can learn easily. As @FritsvanCampen said we don't need module line i believe. Thanks